# Read Windows command line option in Electron renderer process

Tags: windows, process, electron

I have a deployed Electron App in Windows.
I'm trying to add a command line option on the .exe.

> "C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe" -debug

How I can read the debug flag inside my App? I tried with process.argv, but the debug variable isn't there.

Comment: Were you running this in a remote renderer process? If so, that is why you need `require('electron').remote`. For clarification to future readers if you can add that to the question (that it is in a renderer process) that would be awesome :) (and I can update my answer, also)

Comment: Renderer process. You are right, It depends on the process.
Update your answer so I can mark It as the right one. :)

Comment: Great! Updated with both answers for completeness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your arguments are inside the `process.argv` array. So if you are trying to access the arguments from the main process you can just use the following:

```js
//the command you called is always argv[0]
process.argv[0] == "C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe"

//every other argument, separated by spaces, is in the array in order
process.argv[1] == "-debug"
```

If you are trying to access them from a renderer process however, you need to use [electron remote](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md).

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote

//the command you called is always argv[0]
remote.process.argv[0] == "C:\Program Files\MyApp.exe"

//every other argument, separated by spaces, is in the array in order
remote.process.argv[1] == "-debug"
```

Comment: Isn't, there. Sorry.

Comment: Updated with case for renderer process also

Comment: The Renderer Process has no access to `require` when Node Integration is disabled (the default).