# How to use deep linking in electron desktop application similar to mobile application

Tags: javascript, electron, deep-linking

I have developed a desktop application using electron framework. I have created a **custom protocol(Eg: myapp://)** to open URL's with that custom protocol in my desktop application.

I need implement the concept of deep linking used in mobile applications to detect if the URL is from a specific domain to open in the application.
Likewise if user have a link (Eg: myapp.com) to my web app if he click it must prompt the user to open in my desktop application rather that opening it in browser with https protocol.

How can I do it?

That is if I have a link as **myapp://myapp.com** the browser prompts me to open it in my application.
But if the link is **myapp.com** the browser opens it with **https** protocol in the browser itself.

In case of android application we can use intent filter to detect the URL and prompt the user to open it in the respective application.

Likewise is it possible to do detect URL from specific domain and open it in the desktop application if the user had already installed the desktop application else open it in browser?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80650/how-do-i-register-a-custom-url-protocol-in-windows <--- for registering custom protocol handler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45051296/30594 <--- For reading the parameters passed

Comment: @Ramesh The reference link gives information about registering the custom protocol which I have done already. My point is even if it is https protocol say https: //myapp.com  as it contains the domain myapp.com it must be opened in application rather than browser. How to map the domain to my application installed?